# POSTGRESQL: Join columns

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, knex.js

I have a POSTGRESQL version 12.5 database where I have a table that has three columns: `c_id`, `columna` and `columnb`. The three columns can have a different values.

I need to do a join their values into a single object like this:

Here is the sample data
I have a table that has 3 columns with the same type

```
c_id        columna   columnb
1              a       b
2              c       d
3              x       y
```

I need to run a query that will join the columns `columna` and `columnb` like this:

```
c_id       merge_column
1             {"columna":a, "columnb": "b"}
2             {"columna":d, "columnb": "d"}
3             {"columna":x, "columnb": "y"}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the whole row into a JSON, the remove the `c_id` key:

```
select t.c_id, to_jsonb(t) - 'c_id' as merge_column
from the_table t
```

If there are more columns than you have shown, and you only want to get two of them, using `jsonb_build_object()` is probably easier:

```
select t.c_id, 
       jsonb_build_object('columna', t.columna, 'columnb', t.columnb) as merge_column
from the_table t
```